# public static boolean equals method not comparing strings as desired

Tags: java, static, boolean, equals, string-comparison

```
The Grades & Courses are not equal...

Course Title: Physics
Grade: A-

Course Title: Physics
Grade: A-
```

Above is my output. That should not be the case...I am using Equals method (to compare the content of the strings) in the other class as you can see here:

```
//Equals Method
public static boolean equals(CourseGrade a, CourseGrade b) {
    return a.getCourse().equalsIgnoreCase(b.getGrade());
```

Everything seems copacetic -- I'm not thrown any errors. However, as you can see from the output, the answer is wrong. It should be False, and it should output the line, "The Grades & Courses are not equal..." For clarity:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CourseGrade a = new CourseGrade("Physics", "A-");
    CourseGrade b = new CourseGrade("Physics", "A-");

    if (a.equals(b)){
        System.out.println("The Grades & Courses are equal...");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("The Grades & Courses are not equal...");
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(a.toString());
    System.out.println(b.toString());
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why would `course` be equal to `grade`? And based on your code, you're not call `equals(CourseGrade, CourseGrade)`

Comment: You are calling `Object.equals` not your `static` method.

Comment: seems that you want to call `equals(a, b)` not `a.equals(b)` ;)

Comment: Removing static recognizes when they're equal, but now everything is equal to the program @Elliott Frisch

Comment: @alfasin, I tried changing `equals(a,b)` in the client class and it did not work. It said there was an error. What should I do?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I read the "duplicate" you posted, but it doesn't make sense ...all the uses of "object" "o" and other variables are just furthering my confusion.

Comment: @user7484153 go back to that post, read it again and again until you understand it. It's crucial to understand how `equals` work in Java. If that post is not clear enough, google it and read more about the subject until you understand - there are plenty of blog posts that explains the subject.

Comment: Ok, I read the duplicate...and ............it worked. LOL! Who knew what I could do with a little squinting!